# SQL Server MergeReplication with single GUID colum

Tags: sql, replication

i have an table which contains an single column, which is the Primary key, uniqueidentified, rowguid = true. if creating an merge replication, the Agent Fails to start with:

"The article includes only the rowguidcol column. You must publish at least one other column."

is there any way to publish this table, without removing the rowguid and adding an second column?

thx

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the Snapshot Agent is misidentifying your rowguid column as the ROWGUIDCOL required for each table published in Merge Replication.

See the section *Snapshot Considerations* in [Enhance Merge Replication Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152770.aspx) for more information on the column Merge Replication creates and uses to uniquely identify each row in a published article.

Due to the nature of your existing column, will most likely need to add a second dummy column to get this working for Merge Replication.